# Given $x^{93} \equiv 2 \, (\textrm{mod}\ 5)$, $x \equiv \,? \, (\textrm{mod}\ 5)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Given $x^{93} \equiv 2 \, (\textrm{mod}\ 5)$

$x \equiv \,? \, (\textrm{mod}\ 5)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $\gcd(x,5) = 1$. From Euler's Theorem we have $x^4 \equiv 1 (\mod 5)$. Hence

$$
x^{93} \equiv  (x^{4})^{23}.x \equiv x \equiv 2 (\mod 5)
$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Notice that $2^4\equiv 1[5]$ and $93=4\times 23+1$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

You just have to try $5$ numbers.

Try $x$ being $0,1,2,-1,-2$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $x \not\equiv 0 \mod 5$,  $x^{4n} \equiv 1 \mod 5$ for any integer $n$.